# Redirect AFTER response is ended

Tags: python, node.js, express

Hope this is not already answer somewhere else but I cannot find it...

I've created a nodejs script to display in live the output of a python script, see demo :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });  

    PythonShell.run('script_web_e2L.py', function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
         res.writeHead(301,{Location: results[results.length - 1]}); 
       res.end(); 
    }).on('message', function (message) {
        res.write(message+'<br>');
    }); 
});
```

I wish to display all the output of the python script, and at this end, if it reached the end, I would like to redirect link given by the last output of python.

As you must guess, I guess the error :

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Any idea how to overwrite the header or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You writing http response headers twice.

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });  
res.writeHead(301,{Location: results[results.length - 1]});
```

You cannot do that. You must write headers once only, http spec.

To redirect the user after command completion you have to do that on client side.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Could you give me an idea to do that on the client side ? I'me still looking to write javascript  on the client side from Nodejs.